# Can't correctly format imported data in R

Tags: r, import, format, read.table

i'm trying to import a text file to R, which normally I get without problems. But this time, R imports only a fraction of some columns.

This is the input data stored in a plain text file (tab separated):

```
    id_value    NG  treatment_id    treatment   Xcoord  Ycoord
    267  0.14217400000  1a  1   529863.226  5695760.970
    269  0.14218700000  1a  1   529861.792  5695760.404
    270  0.14599500000  1a  1   529862.235  5695758.726
    271  0.15622200000  1a  1   529860.258  5695760.198
    273  0.15795400000  1a  1   529860.679  5695758.050
```

I used the command:

```
interpr <- read.delim("~/interpr")
```

and got this:

```
> interpolation
        id.value     NG      treatment_id treatment   Xcoord  Ycoord
    1        267   0.1421740           1a         1 529863.2 5695761
    2        269   0.1421870           1a         1 529861.8 5695760
    3        270   0.1459950           1a         1 529862.2 5695759
    4        271   0.1562220           1a         1 529860.3 5695760
    5        273   0.1579540           1a         1 529860.7 5695758
```

As you may noticed, the column Xcoord ist rounded to just one decimal place while the column Ycoord is rounded to an integer.

I have tried lot of things. For example, I tried to import the columns as text, and the converting them to numbers using:

```
interpr <- read.delim("~/interpr", colClasses = "character")
interpr$X <- as.double(interpr$Xcoord)
```

At first it imports all numbers, but after transforming (also tried as.numeric) I get the same problem. I need the 3 decimal places, so rounding is not an option for me. I also need it to be defined as number for further prosessing.

Does someone know why this happens? It's the first time I've ever seen this problem...

Comment: Have you tried it with `read.table`?

Comment: This may just be the default `print` number of significant values - appears to be seven here. Internally the numbers may be correct Use `options(digits=10)` then look at your data

Comment: @RichardScriven yes, I have tried read.table. I also tried to save in csv and import with read.csv and even tried to import directly from ods file using gnumeric. Always the same problem.

Comment: @user20650 you were completely right... does this mean that I had always imported it correctly and it's only a matter of the display? What I mean is, would the calculations be made with all decimals (although I just see one)?

Comment: Yes, its imported correctly and the calculations will be fine - this is just how they are displayed on screen.

Comment: Will one of the @user####s please post as an answer? Thanks :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto; gave it a go, please feel free to improve

Comment: @user20650, thanks (and +1)! It's nice to be able to easily *see* that a question has been answered (or at least has a proposed answer).

Comment: Is there a way to mark this as "solved"? or does it remain open to eternity?

Comment: The green tick marks the question as solved - thanks - but users can still offer other answers or improve mine. It remains on site for future searches/users with similar issues. @AnandaMahto - cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the default number of digits that are printed on screen - the default is seven, see `?options` and look for `digits`.

You can change the default by using

```
options(digits=10)
```